# requestLocationUpdates not working on emulator

Tags: android, gps, fusedlocationproviderclient

I'm trying to get gps information by using FusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates.

In real device FusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates works well but on a emulator
it doesn't work.

Callback method is not getting called

This is my code.

```
    public MAgencyViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
    super(application);
    Log.d(TAG,"LocationCallBack instance have been made");
    //LocationCallBack 부분 객체 생성하고 그에 LocatinResult 받았을때를 추상화 시켜주는 부분
    gpt = new GpsTransfer();
    lcb = new LocationCallback(){
        @Override
        public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult){
            if(locationResult == null){
                Log.d(TAG,"Location information have not been recieved");
                return;
            }
            Log.d(TAG,"Location information have been recieved");
            //gps를 통하여서 위도와 경도를 입력받는다.
            for (Location location : locationResult.getLocations()) {
                if (location != null) {
                    gpt.setLon(location.getLongitude());
                    gpt.setLat(location.getLatitude());
                }
            }

            //gps 연결을 닫는다.
            LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(getApplication()).removeLocationUpdates(lcb);

            //x,y 좌표로 변환
            gpt.transfer(gpt,0);
            Log.d(TAG, gpt.toString());
            setGeoInfo(gpt); //변환된 정보를 GeoInfo에 넣음
            mldGi.setValue(gi);
        }
    };
}

@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")//위치권한 체크안해도 된다고 하는 부분 안하는 이유는 SplashActivity에서 이미 했기 때문이다.
public void requestUpdate(LocationRequest locationRequest){

    Log.d(TAG,"LocationRequest have been request");
    mldGi = new MutableLiveData<GeoInfo>();
    requestLocationUpdate = true;
    LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(getApplication())
            .requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest,lcb,null);
}
```

Why doesn't work on emulator?
And How can I solve it??

Comment: just check that if your emulator has google play services in it else it will get failed.